# Errors: Dependencies - not installed, npm - not installed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, npm

I have an Angular2Client and a WebAPI project in a VS2015 solution both showing the following messages in solution explorer:

> Dependencies - not installed
>
> npm - not installed

Several packages under npm also show not installed. I have Node.js 5.7.1 installed.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple projects within VS2015 solution.  One project needs to use EF6 whereas others use EF7.  I was configuring DNVM "globally" for EF7 and overlooking that DNVM needs to be installed separately for this EF6 project.  DNVM upgrade command identifies the necessary version from packages.config file.

THE FIX:
open Developer Prompt for VS2105

cd into the EF6 project's directory and run

@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command “&{$Branch=’dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString(‘https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}”

dnvm upgrade

dnu restore